# How do I display Excel-style cells from A to BJ?

Tags: php, excel

How do I display Excel-style cells from A to BJ ?

```
<?php
for ($i = 'A'; $i <= 'BJ'; $i++) 
{    
    echo $i."<br>";
}   
?>
```

only displays `A` and `B`. I have to stop at `BK` to display till `BJ`. But how does it work till `ZZ` ?

```
<?php
for ($i = 'A'; $i <= 'ZZ'; $i++) 
{    
    if ($i == 'BK') break;
    echo $i."<br>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: what's wrong with the second one?

Comment: I think you just want to swap lines: put `echo $i` above the `if-break´

Comment: I'm quite sure Excel has the letters at the top as columns and not as rows.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough. Why isnt `for ($i = 'A'; $i <= 'BJ'; $i++)`  working ? When it's iterating from A to ZZ, why isn't iteration not working from A to BJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `<=`.... because the comparison is alphabetic when you're comparing strings, and `Z` is less than `ZA`, and `C` > `BJ`... you need to use a `!==` comparison....

take your end point

```
$endpoint = BJ;
```

increment that

```
$endpoint++;
```

then do

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i !== $endpoint; $i++) { ... }
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie - yes to BJ, but the real question is "But how does it work till `ZZ`"?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use chr() function to convert number to letter.

Here I loop from 65 to 126. A= 65 and 126 is well not BJ but 126-65 is the number of columns needed.

```
for ($i = 65; $i <= 126; $i++) 
{   
    If($i > 116){ // more than AZ
         echo "B" . chr($i-52)."<br>\n";
    }ElseIf($i >90){ // more than Z
         echo "A" . chr($i-26)."<br>\n";
    }else{
         echo chr($i)."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/XVIV9